# Where to buy tickets for the DART rail service in Dublin?

Tags: trains, tickets, dublin

Does anyone know where these tickets are sold? I cannot find any information. On the website it's written that you can buy them online but it's a lie.

Comment: I'm talking about the DART in Dublin not the one in the USA

Comment: As an example, http://www.irishrail.ie/travel-information/howth-junction-and-donaghmede is the site of a train station that only serves DART, and it has ticket vending machines. So they are extremely likely to be for DART trains.

Comment: @pnuts - Sure, that's possible. I wanted to express that if there are ticket vending machines at a place that only serves these trains, then very most likely these machines are available also at other DART stations. So the place and time to buy them is right before entering the train and one does not have to plan this ahead and also one doesn't need to buy them in advance online (no clue if that would have saved money, though).

Comment: @miniHouse I know it is difficult to prove a negative but can you please share why you think the site is lying when they say it is possible to buy online?

Comment: @Willeke I just checked: http://journeyplanner.irishrail.ie/ shows "No Price Available" for all journeys that involve a DART train, no matter the route or date. Maybe the site has a temporary failure.

Comment: That is the irish rail site, not the Dart site.

Comment: DART tickets can be purchased from the machine located at each stop along the route. The fare is determined from origin to destination, which you select as you purchase the ticket. Another option is the [Leap Card](https://www.leapcard.ie/en/NavigationPages/CardPurchase.aspx) which can be purchased online and _can be used on DART & Commuter services, Dublin Bus and Luas. Save up to 24% with Leap card versus cash fares._

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, DART tickets cannot be bought online, and it makes no sense to do so as those are commuter trains (this includes one to Howth). There are no reserved seats, and lots of standing space there. Buy them on station from the machine. Their price is fixed.

However, you can indeed buy **long distance** IrishRail tickets online (such as Dublin-Cork or Dublin-Limerick). Note that you still won't get the actual tickets - instead you'll get a number which you need to type into the ticket machine on a train station, and the machine will give you the actual ticket. Thus you're not going to save time. However you might save money - as for those (and only those) tickets you can get much better price if you book sufficiently in advance.